# De la monnaie de singe?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, sens, étymologie

Lorsqu'on parle de monnaie de singe, de quoi s'agit-il ? Et quelle est l'origine de cette expression ?

Comment: On dit aussi *payer en gambades*. Par allusion à l'ancienne coutume selon laquelle les jongleurs acquittaient leur droit en faisant danser leurs singes devant le péage. Source [Dictionnaire de l'Academie françoise] (http://books.google.fr/books?id=0oM-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA801&lpg=PA801&dq=%22Payer+en+gambades%22&source=bl&ots=DX2FSp6pT-&sig=tSISJ-JgyndUQWT2740beJoMGes&hl=fr&ei=Sv23ToP2FoXm-gbMz4SFBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22Payer%20en%20gambades%22&f=false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Payer avec de la monnaie de singe veut dire avec de l'argent qui n'a pas de valeur.
Autrement dit, vous escroquer.
L'expression vient apparemment de Saint Louis qui aurait accordé aux montreurs de singes le droit de payer en grimaces ou en tours de passe-passe le péage du Petit-Pont qui relie l’île Notre-Dame au quartier Saint-Jacques.

Exemple:

- "j'ai passé un contrat avec Jules qui me donne 15% des revenus!"
- "Idiot! Il compte vendre la license à une compagnie! Tu t'es fait payer en monnaie de singe"

Ok l'exemple est idiot mais c'est pas facile de trouver une idée

Answer (score 3):

Pour l'expression moderne, on peut se dire que la monnaie de singe est la cacahuète. Payer en monnaie de singe veut donc dire payer avec des cacahuètes, soit avec quelque chose qui n'a pas de valeur.

Wikipédia attribue cette expression à Saint Louis (avec une signification un peu différente à l'époque):

> Selon les livres des métiers du XIIe siècle, Saint Louis aurait accordé aux montreurs de singes le droit de payer en grimaces ou en tours de passe-passe le péage du Petit-Pont qui relie l’île Notre-Dame au quartier Saint-Jacques [[1](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3fRWAAAAMAAJ&ots=TAbhzKgg89&dq=livres%20des%20m%C3%A9tiers%20du%20XIIe%20si%C3%A8cl&pg=PA287#v=onepage&q=singe&f=false)]

Comment: Je confirme! À Paris, où je vis, j'ai bien plus tendance à entendre des gens parler de rémunération en terme de cacahouètes qu'en monnaie de singe.