# Origine de l'expression « gagner des cacahuètes »

Tags: expressions, étymologie

L'expression *gagner des cacahuètes* signifie « gagner un faible salaire ».

D'où vient cette expression ?

Si je devais inventer une théorie je dirais que c'est tout ce que les singes gagnent au cirque, mais je n'ai aucune référence.

[Exemple](http://resultat-exploitations.blogs.liberation.fr/finances/2012/06/tr%C3%A8s-lib%C3%A9ral-roland-garros.html) :

> Il y a donc une vraie précarisation des "petits joueurs" qui doivent payer un coach, un kiné, un physio et leurs déplacements pour gagner des cacahuètes pendant que Nadal, Federer ou Djokovic se gavent.

Comment: Au québec, on parle plus de « Gagner des peanuts »

Answer (score 4):

Si cette expression est parfois, très rarement d'ailleurs, employée par des journalistes en français, elle est considérée comme un anglicisme, c'est la traduction littérale de *earn peanuts* (expression argotique qui veut dire gagner très peu, voire même une somme insuffisante par rapport au travail fourni).
En français on dit « gagner des clopes » (ou « des clopinettes »). *Peanuts*, comme *clopes*, sont employés pour signifier « une toute petite quantité », « presque rien ». Ces deux expressions sont à peu près contemporaines et datent de première moitié du XXème siècle.

Il existe par contre en français une expression qui remonte au XII ème siècle : « [payer en monnaie de singe](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/de-la-monnaie-de-singe) » qui nous ramène aux singes (mais pas aux cacahuètes qui étaient je crois inconnues en Europe au Moyen-Âge).

Comment: Une source ? Je reste sceptique sur le fait que ça soit un anglicisme. J'ai souvent entendu cette expression sous d'autres formes. Mais bon, mon avis là dessus ne vaut probablement pas trois cacahuètes… À part ça, *payer en monnaie de singe* n'a pas du tout le même sens.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: J'ai même aussi déjà entendu *c'est peanuts* en français dans le texte. Je pensais que c'était un québéquisme parce qu'il me semble qu'on dit *pinotte* pour *cacahuète* au Québec. Le sens de *payer en monnaie de singe* est indiqué dans le lien que je donnais et bien sûr ça ne veut pas dire la même chose.

Comment: @Stephane ...pas du tout le même sens ? *être payé en monnaie de singe* / *gagner des cacahuètes* ? Je n'irai pas jusqu'à dire que ce sont des équivalents, mais il y a une grande proximité de sens quand même... (l'un impliquant très souvent l'autre).